# In Unity TestRunner, clicking "Run All" results with a failed test case. But when I run tests individually they passes. Why that?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, testing

I am using - Unity 2020.3.11f1

One test only passes when It is run individually. When all tests are run, it always fails. These test are responsible for spawning blocks in the scene at random intervals.

The error message I got:

```
SpawnMultipleBlocks (0.020s)
---
Unhandled log message: '[Exception] NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. Use UnityEngine.TestTools.LogAssert.Expect
---
BlockSpawner+<SpawnedBlocks>d__14.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/BlockSpawner.cs:69)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <127e81e1cb3441cc97d26b1910daae77>:0)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
BlockSpawner:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/BlockSpawner.cs:24)
---
topPos is null
Generate at top : 0
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
topPos is null
Generate at top : 0
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
topPos is null
Generate at top : 0
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I have create a test class - `BlockSpawnerTests.cs`
Content of it,

```
using System.Collections;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;

namespace Tests
{

    public class BlockSpawnerTests : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private static string resourceDirPath = "Tests/Block";

        [Test]
        public void SpawnBlock()
        {
            // Arrange
            var spawner = new GameObject().AddComponent<BlockSpawner>();
            spawner.setBlockReference(Resources.Load<GameObject>(resourceDirPath));

            // Act
            spawner.SpawnBlock(Vector3.zero);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(spawner.getSpawnedBlock());
        }

        [Test]
        public void SpawnBlockAtPosition()
        {
            // Arrange
            var spawner = new GameObject().AddComponent<BlockSpawner>();
            spawner.setBlockReference(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Tests/Block"));

            // Act
            spawner.SpawnBlock(Vector3.one);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(spawner.getSpawnedBlock().transform.position, Vector3.one);
        }

        [Test]
        public void SpawnBlockSpeed()
        {
            // Arrange
            var spawner = new GameObject().AddComponent<BlockSpawner>();
            spawner.setBlockReference(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Tests/Block"));

            // Act
            spawner.SpawnBlock(Vector3.zero);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(spawner.getSpawnedBlock().GetComponent<Block>().GetSpeed() >= -10
                && spawner.getSpawnedBlock().GetComponent<Block>().GetSpeed() <= -4);
        }

        [Test]
        public void WhenBlockComponentIsNullShouldLog()
        {
            // Arrange
            var spawner = new GameObject().AddComponent<BlockSpawner>();
            spawner.setBlockReference(new GameObject("EmptyObject"));

            // Act
            spawner.SpawnBlock(Vector3.zero);

            // Assert
            LogAssert.Expect(LogType.Log, "Spawned block doesn't have a Block component");
            LogAssert.NoUnexpectedReceived();
            Destroy(spawner);
        }

        [UnityTest]
        public IEnumerator SpawnMultipleBlocks()
        {
            Debug.Log("block spawner create");
            var spawner = new GameObject();
            var blockSpawner = spawner.AddComponent<BlockSpawner>();
            Debug.Log("set top bottom middle");
            blockSpawner.SetTopPos(new GameObject().transform);
            blockSpawner.SetBottomPos(new GameObject().transform);
            blockSpawner.SetMiddlePos(new GameObject().transform);

            blockSpawner.SetWaitForSpawnLow(1);
            blockSpawner.SetWaitForSpawnHigh(2);
            blockSpawner.setBlockReference(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Tests/Block"));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            blockSpawner.Start();

            // wait for at least 1 block to be spawned
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            Assert.GreaterOrEqual(blockSpawner.GetSpawnedBlocks().Count, 1);

            // wait for at least 2 block to be spawned
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            Assert.GreaterOrEqual(blockSpawner.GetSpawnedBlocks().Count, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Results I get for `Run All`,
[Results for Run All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q7yb.png)

Results I get for `Run Selected` in same order of tests,
[Results for Run Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zyGt.png)

Comment: general hint: Not all your tests do properly clean up ... and note that `Destroy(spawner);` **only** destroys the `BlockSpawner` component, **not** the created `GameObject` ... I would assume some kind of race condition somewhere that doesn't occur when running the tests individually ... is there anything `static` involved?

Comment: Can you also include the error messages themselves?

Comment: Also could you show us `BlockSpawner.cs` line `69` (nice! :P ) and a bit of context? ;)